# I opened my python script and found 3 additional lines I did not write

Tags: python, github, python-idle

These lines just appeared in my code:

```
<<<<<<<HEAD

followed by ~20 normal lines

=======

followed by ~15 normal lines

>>>>>>> 6cba... 40 characters of hexadecimal. So a hash of something? Why would that be here?
```

These 3 lines were 100% not in my code the last time I saved it, and I'm the only one working on it. Does anyone know what I'm looking at?

I'm using github, but these 3 lines don't show up in the version I committed yesterday. Writing in IDLE, python 3.11.4 on a Windows 11 machine.

Comment: Might be an IDE thing, can you open the .py file in a text editor and see if the lines come up?

Comment: The lines are still there when opened with notepad++

Comment: You had a conflict between the local code and the version in the repository; one of the options for resolving such a conflict puts this `diff` output (showing both versions) in the file, so you can manually pick what to keep.

Comment: @SurajShourie The conflict marker lines are in the file itself and have nothing to do with IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you got this merge conflict marker, but these 9 lines

```
<<<<<<<HEAD

followed by ~20 normal lines

=======

followed by ~15 normal lines

>>>>>>> 6cba... 40 characters of hexadecimal.
```

indicate that version 'HEAD' has the indicated 3 lines (2 blank) with '20' while version '6cba...' (a hex digest of a commit) has the nearly identical 3 lines but with '15' instead of '20'.  In any case, you must remove the 3 conflict marker lines beginning with '<...', '=...', and '>...' and one set of content lines, so you end up with just 3 lines of content.

You may have to somehow indicate that you have resolved the conflict by clicking a button in a git IDE window or write a git command in the command-line terminal.  (Neither is done in the editor itself.)